# ASP.Net Redirect to secure

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, iis, redirect

I am wanting to redirect a page to a secure connection for an ASPX file.

Clients are asked to copy and paste a URL that looks like this `foo.com.au` into the browser.

I have this code below working on the code behind file but am wondering when it is deployed to production if this will update the URL to have `www` after the `https://www` as the URL provided to clients does not have `www` in it?

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreInit(e);
        if (!Request.IsLocal && !Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            string redirectUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:");
            Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using Request.Url, use [Request.Url.AbsoluteUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri.aspx). In addition, you should not assume that the URL will be entered in lowercase. I would revise the code to be:

```
if (!Request.IsLocal && !Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    if (Request.Url.Scheme.Equals(Uri.UriSchemeHttp, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        string sNonSchemeUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(Uri.UriSchemeHttp.Length);
        // Ensure www. is prepended if it is missing
        if (!sNonSchemeUrl.StartsWith("www", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
            sNonSchemeUrl = "www." + sNonSchemeUrl;
        }
        string redirectUrl = Uri.UriSchemeHttps + sNonSchemeUrl;
        Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
    }
}
```

If you do this, all it will change is the schema. So, if the absoluteUri is

```
http://foo.com.au
```

it will be changed to

```
https://foo.com.au
```

One last note: when we have done this, we have never tried it in OnPreInit, we always perform this logic in Page_Load. I am not sure what, if any, ramifications there will be for redirecting at that portion of the page lifecycle, but if you run into issues, you could move it into Page_Load.

Comment: Thanks, the last part is making sure `www` is placed in the URL (if it is not there) as the certificate is for `https://www.foo.com.au` and not `https://foo.com.au` @competent_tech

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that is necessary, but it should be a straightforward test of the URI to see if it starts with www and add it if not. I can revise the answer to show this.

Comment: @ojhawkins: ok, answer has been modified to include addition of www. if it is missing.

Comment: Yes I am not sure either as it is difficult to test as the certificate works in production and not else where

Answer (score 0):

This was my final implementation to account for a request comes through for `https://foo` and not `https://www.foo`

```
        if (!Request.IsLocal &&
            !Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith("https://www.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            string translatedUrl;
            string nonSchemeUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            string stringToReplace = (Request.Url.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp ? Uri.UriSchemeHttp + "://" : Uri.UriSchemeHttps + "://");
            nonSchemeUrl = nonSchemeUrl.Replace(stringToReplace, string.Empty);
            if (!nonSchemeUrl.StartsWith("www", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))nonSchemeUrl = "www." + nonSchemeUrl;
            translatedUrl = Uri.UriSchemeHttps + "://" + nonSchemeUrl;
            Response.Redirect(nonSchemeUrl);
        }
```

Comment: you are never using your variable translatedUrl